# Redirect from one url to another using .htaccess in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

If my url is

`http://localhost/1/Qzz/images/`

then i have to redirect to this

`http://localhost/1/Qzz/`  or  `http://localhost/1/Qzz/index.php` .

How i write the required code in **.htaccess** file. I tried like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %^http://localhost/1/Qzz/images$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/1/Qzz/index.php/$1 [R,L]
```

this obtained from google but no luck. I am getting **internal server error**. Same error is get when try the below code

```
Redirect http://localhost/1/Qzz/images  http://localhost/1/Qzz/index.php
```

I need your help....

Comment: can you please try with this `Redirect 301 /1/Qzz/images/ http://localhost/1/Qzz/index.php`

Comment: i don't know what happened. I already tried this code before but not worked, now tried once more as you said then worked. may be some typo or other. Whatever it is your comment helped me any ways thank you so much..

Comment: :) nice that it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

As *Prava-MindfireSolutions* said if use

```
Redirect 301 http://localhost/1/Qzz/images/ http://localhost/1/Qzz/index.php
```

then it will work.

For more information:  https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489